# How to describe these solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

This is a homogeneous equation of $Ax=0$, so the last column represents the right side of the system.

How can I describe this solution? It's just a 2-D plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Comment: If the subspace has basis $\langle -2, -3, 1\rangle$, write down all the elements of that subspace using set notation (for example). What kind of space is that?

Comment: @rogerl huhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @MathStackExchange Why was the question changed? The changed question has another solution.

Comment: @Eff its 2 dimensional solution space?

Comment: @MathStackExchange Create a new question if you want to ask another question.

Comment: @Eff why cant you just say yes/no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $z$ component can be any real number whatsoever. Let's just put $z = t$, $\;t\in \mathbb R$.

Then the set of solutions is given by $\{\langle -2t, -3t, t\rangle^T \mid t \in \mathbb Z\}$. You'll see that when $z = t = 1$, we have the basis vector $\langle -2, -3, 1\rangle^T$.

Comment: so the sol space is a line?

Comment: Yes indeed, Math.

Answer (score 1):

So the basis of the null space is the vector $(-2,-3,1)^T$. This vector is a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but when we say that the vector is a basis we mean that
$$\text{Nullspace}(A) = \text{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix}t,\quad t\in\mathbb{R} $$
This forms a line in three dimensional space in the direction of the vector.